# systemctl + what is the meaning of Restart=always

Tags: systemd, configuration, services

I configured the service - calc_mem.service

as the following

```
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
StartLimitInterval=400
StartLimitBurst=3
```

the configuration above should do the following from my understanding

**the service have 3 retries when service exit with error**

**and before service start it will wait 5 seconds**

also I found that "Restart" can be also:

```
Restart=always
```

I can understand that need to restart the service on failure
but what is the meaning of   `Restart=always` ?

in which case we need to set -  `Restart=always`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [`systemd.service` man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) has a description of the values `Restart=` takes, and a table of what options cause a restart when. `Always` pretty much does what it says on the lid:

> If set to `always`, the service will be restarted regardless of whether it exited cleanly or not, got terminated abnormally by a signal, or hit a timeout.

I don't know for sure what situation they had in mind for that feature, but we might hypothesise e.g. a service configured to only run for a fixed period of time or to serve fixed number of requests and to then stop to avoid any possible resource leaks. Having systemd do the restarting makes for a cleaner implementation of the service itself.

In some sense, we might also ask why *not* include that option in systemd. Since it is capable of restarting services on failure, they might as well include the option of restarting the service *always*, just in case someone needs it. To provide tools, not policy.

Note also that a "successful exit" here is defined rather broadly:

> If set to `on-success`, it will be restarted only when the service process exits cleanly. In this context, a clean exit means an exit code of 0, or one of the signals `SIGHUP`, `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM` or `SIGPIPE`, *[...]*

`SIGHUP` is a common way of asking a process to restart, but it unhandled, it 
terminates the process. So having `Restart=always` (or `Restart=on-success`) allows to use `SIGHUP` for restarting, even without the service itself supporting that.

Also, as far as I can read the man page, `always` doesn't mean it would override the limits set by `StartLimitInterval` and `StartLimitBurst`:

> Note that service restart is subject to unit start rate limiting configured with `StartLimitIntervalSec=` and `StartLimitBurst=`, see systemd.unit(5) for details. A restarted service enters the failed state only after the start limits are reached.

Comment: Very nice answer.  This helped me find the definition for `Reason=on-abort` as well.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564443/what-does-restart-on-abort-mean-in-a-systemd-service/564444#564444

Answer (score 3):

> If set to **on-failure**, the service will be restarted when the process exits with a non-zero exit code, is terminated by a signal (including on core dump, but excluding the aforementioned four signals), when an operation (such as service reload) times out, and when the configured watchdog timeout is triggered. [...] If set to **always**, the service will be restarted regardless of whether it exited cleanly or not, got terminated abnormally by a signal, or hit a timeout.

Excerpt from https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

So if you set `on-failure`, it won't get restarted on clean exit.

Comment: ok now its clearly , about my configuration , do you see some issue with my configuration ? or this is exactly what should be in order to restart 3 try on fail

Answer (score 3):

@JdeBP suggested there is another way to look at this question.

`Restart=always` is simpler.  Easier to implement, easier to understand.  Why would we ever want check whether the service terminated with exit code 0 (`EXIT_SUCCESS`) ?  There might even have been a weird bug / error in the service, that caused it to terminate with exit code 0 when it should not have done so.

Answer 1: There are some units that must not use `Restart=always`.  In particular, if the service exits after an idle timeout.

Intriguingly, it would not matter so much if a bug/error causes such a service to exit "successfully", when it should not have done so.  Because an idle timeout implies that the service has already been set up to start automatically when a new request is made.

However `Restart=on-failure` might be used for a service which can exit on idle in some configurations, but not in others.  [`systemd-networkd` uses it for this reason](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/a97dcc12e486ecff531809802930a26c4da827f2).

Answer 2: System administration practices may include killing or messaging service processes to stop them.  Sometimes people use a plain `kill` command, but there are also scripts like `apachectl`.  The advantage of `Restart=on-failure` is that it is less risky for `systemd` to recommend using it (as the man page does).

However `systemd` is left in a strange position, where they also support `Restart=always`, and that is what they like to set for the majority of long-running services inside the `systemd` project...  This does not seem very helpful when you are trying to learn about `systemd` service definitions.

Comment: This is somewhat backwards.  Unconditional restart is actually the behaviour of long standing, from quite a number of existing service managers over the decades.  It's adding all of the _conditional_ restarts, based upon process exit code and status, that is the extra complexity that came later.  I speak as one of the people who has implemented such things, several times over.  And indeed this was the history of systemd development, too.

Comment: @JdeBP edited.  It is not so obvious when you are coming across this afterwards, and just see a list of possible options.  Thanks for your perspective :-).

Comment: @JdeBP my guess that this was about various bus-activated units which terminate after inactivity does not seem to be right though.  `systemd-timedated.service` does not bother with `Restart=on-failure`... and I guess there is no reason that it should.  Hmm, plenty of other services seem to use it though, including `systemd-networkd`.  So I wonder what they have in common.

Comment: [too-conservative thinking](https://jdebp.uk/FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/daemonize.html#right)

Comment: @JdeBP made me smile :-). `networkd` turns out to be a more complex compromise, I can understand that.  But then leaving `Restart=always` in all the other systemd daemons seems so confusing to me.  It's like there's a subtle advantage that `systemd` strongly cares about, and simultaneously doesn't think is important enough to document.