# What does Restart=on-abort mean in a systemd service?

Tags: systemctl

I'm using a service and it is dying (stopping) unexpectedly.  I want to get it to restart automatically no matter how it stops!  It is configured for `Restart=on-abort` and it is not restarting.  I didn't write the service, it came from another vendor so while I want to track down the root cause of the service crashing, I also need a solution to keep the system running until I can find the root cause.  The service dies zero to three times a day so not too frequently.

The service currently is set to `Restart=on-abort` as defined in the service file at `/etc/systemd/system/someone-elses.service`

**So what does `Restart=on-abort` mean?**

I did a search and to learn what the different values of restart= mean and found nothing in the man page:

- [systemctl man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemctl.1.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The systemd.service can be configured to restart a service based on a number of conditions.  [This systemctl man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) has a good explanation of the reasons and reasons are included in this answer so this answer can stand alone.

The definition for `Restart=on-abort` is  *the service will be restarted only if the service process exits due to an uncaught signal not specified as a clean exit status.*  This means a signal other than  SIGHUP, SIGINT, SIGTERM or SIGPIPE.  These 4 signals are described as **clean signals** by the systemctl man page.

In my case I actually wanted `Restart=always` because regardless of how the process died or exited, I wanted it to be restarted.  The property `RestartSec=15s` is important for me because I want some time between restarts to prevent constently restarting (I don't expect this to happen but that is why I have this setting).

The following is take from the [systemctl man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) and formatted for SO:

> **Restart=** values can be `no`, `on-success`, `on-failure`, `on-abnormal`, `on-watchdog`,`on-abort`, or `always`.

Each of these values is explained next:

> **no** (*the default*) - If set to `no` the service will not be restarted.
>
> **success** - If set to `on-success`, it will be restarted only when the
>   service process exits cleanly.   In this context, a clean exit means an
>   exit code of 0, or one of the signals SIGHUP, SIGINT, SIGTERM or
>   SIGPIPE, and additionally, exit statuses and signals specified in
>   SuccessExitStatus=.
>
> **on-failure** - If set to `on-failure`, the service will be
>   restarted when the process exits with a non-zero exit code, is
>   terminated by a signal (including on core dump, but excluding the
>   aforementioned four signals), when an operation (such as service
>   reload) times out, and when the configured watchdog timeout is
>   triggered.
>
> **on-abnormal** - If set to `on-abnormal`, the service will be restarted when
>   the process is terminated by a signal (including on core dump,
>   excluding the aforementioned four signals), when an operation times
>   out, or when the watchdog timeout is triggered.
>
> **on-abort** - If set to `on-abort`, the service will be restarted only if the service process exits due to
>   an uncaught signal not specified as a clean exit status. If set to
>   on-watchdog, the service will be restarted only if the watchdog
>   timeout for the service expires.
>
> **always** - If set to `always`, the service will be
>   restarted regardless of whether it exited cleanly or not, got
>   terminated abnormally by a signal, or hit a timeout.

See also this wonderful answer!  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507917/119816