# Restart=on-abort in systemd will service autostart when server is restarted?

Tags: systemd

Given I cannot test it by restarting the production server, if the service is set to `Restart=on-abort`, will it start automatically after I restarted the server?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564443/what-does-restart-on-abort-mean-in-a-systemd-service can probably help you.

Comment: yes I have been there before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Restart` setting is not related to the initial starting of the service at all. The service is started if it is enabled (see `systemctl status servicename`) or if it is required by another service which is started.

Answer (score 0):

The service is started, automatically if the service is placed in the appropriate 'target' and enabled.
Example, to find the default target level,

```
systemctl get-default
```

and that the service is enabled, and it's pre-requisites are met.

`restart="on-abort"` seems to be of specific interest in case of failures.

A service may fail for various reasons. `restart="on-abort"` will restart the service only if the service aborted.